# Deploy WAR file C panel (quick2host)

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment, cpanel

I have a WAR file and I have to deploy it to server. For this I purchased shared hosting (Tomcat is shared) from quick2host.com. Now I am not able to deploy my WAR file through c panel. The representatives are unable to send me logs or error. When I deployed same war to my localhost Tomcat, it's working fine.

The war file is build from `grails war` command.
The project runs on Grails.

Comment: I don't know anything about that provider, but if they can't give you access to log files you should look elsewhere. http://lowendbox.com/ is a great resource for inexpensive hosting

Comment: What version of tomcat are you using at home and on the server?  cPanel is very particular about tomcat versions and it's possible your application needs a different tomcat version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to deploy it through your tomcat admin panel ? Please try with that and let us know if you are getting any error logs